# Google I'm Feeling Lucky URL

Tags: vb.net, url, google-search, url-parameters

So, I've spent about 2 hours trying to get the *I'm Feeling Lucky* URL to work. It seems the URL doesn't like the periods in the search parameter, so does anyone have any potential tricks?

Search Value= 40.840.1/8Z

The first result in a regular Google search is the correct page.

Here's what I've tried:

http://www.google.com/search?btnI=I&q=40.840.1/8Z

http://www.google.com/search?btnI=I&q=40.840.1%2F8Z

http://www.google.com/search?btnI=I&q=40%2E840%2E1/8Z

http://www.google.com/search?btnI=I&q=40%2E840%2E1%2F8Z

http://www.google.com/search?btnI=I&q=40%2F840%2F1%2F8Z
(That one was actually pretty close)

http://www.google.com/search?btnI=I&q=40%20840%201%208Z

And all of the above surrounded in quotes (%22)

The problem is that the *I'm Feeling Lucky* aspect doesn't work. It finds the correct results, it just doesn't navigate to the first result. I'm open to alternatives besides the *I'm Feeling Lucky* URL parameters as well.

I'm trying to implement this into a .NET application that provides employees with resource information, which is best received from the manufacturer's website(s). The trick is that the resources are from many different suppliers and the links need to be somewhat automatic. Basically I don't whomever manages the software to update these links. To navigate, I'm simply using the `Process.Start("http://www.example.com/")` command which uses the default browser to navigate to the address.

[This post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10699/url-format-for-googles-im-feeling-lucky) helped a lot by the way.

Comment: I always thought this was a trinket Google added to entrain people. I don't think it was ever intended to be invoked via URL. I see the latest rev scrolls there a bunch of 'lucky' topics. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: you can create a google custom search engine of your own, and either exclude certain site or include specific sites only http://cse.google.com

Comment: @Mousey - Your suggestion definitely helped, if you create an Answer I'll mark it. Reading through the documentation, it doesn't look like it supports the redirect function that the "I'm Feeling Lucky" button/parameter provides. But, the Custom Search Engine greatly reduces the number of site to choose from which is alright in the big scheme of things... If it becomes a problem, I'll just use the XML API and redirect from either a web page or application. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @rheitzman The use case is for ease of maintenance. For example, the URL to the current [Java 8 JRE](http://www.google.com/search?btnI=I&q=java%20jre%208) download without having to update it 4 times a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a google custom search engine of your own, and either exclude certain sites or include specific sites only, use http://cse.google.com to do this.

There is a [SO tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-custom-search) for google custom search

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to get any closer than your closest one.
But if it helps, here's an alternative way of writing the "I'm feeling lucky" URL.

http://google.com/search?q=haimer+usa+40%2F840%2F1%2F8Z&btnI

Answer (score 1):

What I did to find the right url is to navigate to google.com. After this I turned my internet connection off. I entered the search details and pressed submit. You can now see the url in the address bar, but it doesn't redirect you to the first result. You can now copy the url and see how google treats your dots and other weird characters.

So to recap:

1. Go to google.com
2. Turn your internet connection off
3. Enter search term
4. Press 'I'm feeling lucky'
5. Copy the url from the address bar